# In Emacs, how can I open a buffer/file in "ibuffer/dired mode" in another frame?

Tags: emacs, elisp

When I am working with multiple frames, I want to decide in which frame Emacs should open files/buffers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that out of the box.

There are `find-buffer-other-frame` and the like but they open a *new* frame.

What you can do is write your own function like this:

```
(defun find-file-in-frame ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively 'select-frame-by-name)
  (call-interactively 'find-file))
```

This switches frame and *then* asks for the file, if you want to do it otherwise you have to do more work.

Edit: Here the version that asks in the current frame and opens the file in the other window:

```
(defun find-file-in-frame (noselect)
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((current-frame (selected-frame))
        (frame (completing-read "Frame: " (make-frame-names-alist)))
        (buffer (save-window-excursion
                  (call-interactively 'find-file))))
    (select-frame-set-input-focus (assoc-default frame
                                                 (make-frame-names-alist)
                                                 nil current-frame))
    (switch-to-buffer buffer)
    (when noselect
      (select-frame-set-input-focus current-frame))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just referring to `find-file`, then I would suggest that with the combination of `windmove` and [`framemove`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FrameMove), switching to the frame in which you wish to open the file is so trivial and fast that you probably don't need anything fancier.

OTOH if you want to be able to select a frame whenever a file is to be opened by any means, this obviously doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're really asking. But as to opening a file from Dired in another frame, just use <kbd>C-o</kbd> or <kbd>M-mouse-2</kbd> in [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/DiredPlus).  Those are bound to these commands, in case you do not want to load **Dired+** for some reason:

```
    (defun diredp-find-file-other-frame ()  ; Bound to `C-o'
      "In Dired, visit this file or directory in another frame."
      (interactive)
      (find-file-other-frame (file-name-sans-versions (dired-get-filename nil t) t)))

    (defun diredp-mouse-find-file-other-frame (event) ; Bound to `M-mouse-2'
      "In Dired, visit file or directory clicked on in another frame."
      (interactive "e")
      (let ((pop-up-frames  t)) (dired-mouse-find-file-other-window event)))
```